# Lupdate doesn't work

Tags: windows, qt

I'm trying to run lupdate on my .pro file and this is what I see. Nothing happens next and .ts files aren't created. My OS is Win10 as seen from picture. I'm using Qt 5.10.1 with MinGW. Also I've tried to run lupdate on Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems that it works properly. Can somebody please help me with this issue?

```
QT += quick
QT += quickcontrols2
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += console

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT


# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    shoppinglistmodel.cpp \
    loggingcategories.cpp \
    logger.cpp \
    purchase.cpp


RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    shoppinglistmodel.h \
    loggingcategories.h \
    logger.h \
    purchase.h

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\boost_1_66_0"

DISTFILES += 

TRANSLATIONS = sh_lst_ru.ts \
    sh_lst_ua.ts
```

[image]

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: Added .pro file text to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** It seems that if you are using boost libraries in project that should be translated you have to involve `TR_EXCLUDE` option in your .pro file.
Here's the one from mine, maybe it will help somebody:

```
TR_EXCLUDE = C:\boost_1_66_0\*
```